# Write characteristic on BLE devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

can anyone help me with Write characteristic on BLE devices?i would need detail explanation i`m reading tutorials but i get more confused. Please help me.
Now i´m working with read characteristic and i´m able to check the notification that is sending me the other device with no problem. What i need now is to be able to send information from my aplication to the other device; making that my device could act as a Server. (BluetoothGattServer)
i´m working with android application.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What have you tried so far? Do you have any sample source code of what you have tried that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need to do is to implement the onCharacteristicWriteRequest function. Then in it check whether you need to store the buffers to combine them later by checking the value of preparedWrite.

Then if you need to combine the whole buffer later on, you need to store the buffers and know the order. then when the onExecuteWrite is called with execute set to true, you would combine the buffers, otherwise you would cancel the write.

Full exanmple of the logic descriped here can be found from my github repo's [BLEAdvertiserLollipop.java](https://github.com/DrJukka/BLETestStuff/blob/master/BleGgOne/app/src/main/java/org/thaliproject/p2p/bleggone/BLEAdvertiserLollipop.java) file.

Answer (score 0):

you can find an implementation of writeCharacteristic in this [repo](https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt)
basically you must implement it in your service:

```
public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] value) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        characteristic.setValue(value);
    }
```

and then call it from your activity.